# SQL: How return more record by recursive queries in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

data source table:

```
name  count
a      2
b      3
```

expect:

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
b3
```

I want to try(but failed):

```
select t.name||level
  from  t
CONNECT BY LEVEL<=t.count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle 11g+, you can use recursive queries:

```
with cte(name, ind, count) as (
      select t.name, 1 as ind, t.count
      from t
      union all
      select cte.name, cte.ind + 1, cte.count
      from cte
      where cte.ind < cte.count
     )
select cte.name || cte.ind
from cte;
```

I prefer recursive CTEs to `CONNECT BY` because the former are standard and supported by most databases.

Comment: @zhanzezhu . . . Ooops, I left out the column names.

Answer (score 0):

You did well, but you should add group by clause to upper select statement.

```
select d from 
(select (t.NAME || level)d
  from  Test t
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.CT)
group by d
order by d
```

works well.